# How Do I serialize a COM object in .Net?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, com-interop, delphi.net

I need serialize a Com Object using .net using c# or Delphi .Net
is this possible?

Comment: Surely someone has code samples?

Comment: @Robert: why would there be any code samples? This question doesn't even make any sense, in general. Does the COM object know anything about XML? Does it know how to serialize itself? Is it even possible to create an instance of the object with default parameters, then set all properties (as you'd have to do when deserializing)?

Comment: @JohnSaunders there are serializers which work through reflection on an object; the object itself doesn't have to know anything about it. And also I thought COM objects had to have a public parameterless constructor, so it ought to be able to create one and then set its values.

Comment: @DaveInCaz: that assumes all the important bits of the COM object are available via reflection (`IDispatch`). In general, that won't be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do this by wrapping the COM object in a (serializable) .NET class, exposing the fields that you want serialized.

Comment: That would almost be as much work as serializing the class manually. Probably fine for a one-off case or a small # of classes, but it wouldn't work as a general-purpose serialization strategy.

Answer (score 5):

Check to see if you COM object implements [IPersistStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690091(VS.85).aspx), [IPersistMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768210(VS.85).aspx) or any other of the [IPersist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688695(VS.85).aspx) variants -- that would be your best bet.

Comment: The Com Object does not implements any IPersistent variant.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a Managed `Object` through [GetObjectForIUnknown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getobjectforiunknown.aspx) Method. And then, you can serialize this managed object.

Answer (score 0):

Not simply by passing object to serializer - implement ISerializable interface on COM object wrapper (primary interop assembly is a wrapper too) and define your own serialization.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to serialize COM objects brought into C# via standard runtime-callable-wrapper COM interop.

This should work as long as the object being serialized uses the type of the interop-generated **class** - not an **interface**.

Say that the type of the object you want to serialize as `SomeType` in the original / native code. In the Visual Studio object browser you should see several rough equivalents in the interop library:

- Interface `SomeType`
- Interface `_SomeType`
- Class `SomeTypeClass`

*It is the last one* which must be used for serialization, apparently.

(At least this is how VB6-based classes show up).

To get this to work, set a reference in C# code to the COM DLL. Visual Studio should autogenerate an interop DLL. (The process of generating the interop DLL involves inspecting the typelib metadata of the COM DLL and using that to generate managed classes. So all the information needed for reflection-based serialization to work ought to be available.)

Then, some sample code:

```
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented,                
    };

    var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);

    using (var gz = new GZipStream(File.OpenWrite(filespec), CompressionMode.Compress))
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(gz))
    using (var writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, objectToSerialize);
    }
```

This should write out the JSON serialized version of `objectToSerialize` to a GZIP-compressed file.

---

Note - this answer was [based on info in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52411499/serialize-a-com-object-to-json/52412110#52412110).

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure there will be difference in how you serialize your data in C++, .Net or in any other language.
COM object is like a class and can be serialized by getting each data member and serializing it .I did like this in C++.

I think this should be same in .Net unless there are specific APIs to do it.